# Qt hide empty submenus

Tags: c++, qt

I have some child `QMenu`s inside a parent menu. After some `&QMenu::aboutToShow` code I have, some of the submenus' actions are hidden and sometimes the submenus are left empty (without any actions inside them).

How can I automatically hide those empty submenus?

Comment: I think it would be a good idea for you to include the QMenu::aboutToShow code you have. I guess that in that code you may loop over the submenus and hide those that are empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to say without seeing you code but... I'm guessing the real issue isn't hiding the empty submenu itself but rather hiding the 'tag' text associated with the submenu in its parent.  To do that you need to hide the `QAction` associated with the submenu rather than simply hiding the submenu.

The following appears to do what (I think) you want...

```
void hide_the_empties (QMenu *menu)
{
  if (!menu)
    return;

  /*
   * The following statement is the one I think you need to
   * add to your own aboutToShow implementation.
   */
  menu->menuAction()->setVisible(!menu->isEmpty());

  if (!menu->isEmpty()) {
    for (auto action: menu->actions()) {
      if (auto m = action->menu()) {
        hide_the_empties(m);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tested with...

```
QMenu menu;
menu.addAction("First");
menu.addAction("Second");

/*
 * Add empty submenu.
 */
auto *sm = menu.addMenu("Not empty if you can see this");

menu.addAction("Third");

QObject::connect(&menu, &QMenu::aboutToShow,
                 [&]()
                 {
                   hide_the_empties(&menu);
                 });
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());

/*
 * Populate submenu.
 */
auto *a1 = sm->addAction("Sub action 1");
auto *a2 = sm->addAction("Sub action 2");
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());

/*
 * Clear submenu again.
 */
sm->clear();
menu.exec(QCursor::pos());
```